# AtomicInteger and Math.max

Tags: java, thread-safety, atomic

I was trying to get the maximum value of a calculatedValue in a cycle and I wanted it to be thread safe. So I decided to use AtomicInteger and Math.max, but I can't find a solution so that the operation can be considered atomic.

```
AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(0);


// Having some cycle here... {
    Integer anotherCalculatedValue = ...;
    value.set(Math.max(value.get(), anotherCalculatedValue));
}

return value.get()
```

The problem with that is that I make two operations, therefore is not threadsafe. How can I solve this? The only way is to use `synchronized`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If Java 8 is available you can use:

```
AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(0);
Integer anotherCalculatedValue = ...;
value.getAndAccumulate(anotherCalculatedValue, Math::max);
```

Which from the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#getAndAccumulate-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-) will:

> Atomically updates the current value with the results of
>     applying the given function to the current and given values,
>     returning the previous value.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I wanted to know the maximum number of threads that were ever active so I put this at the start of my run() method (with a decrement at the end):
`public void run()
    {
        int actNow=activeCount.incrementAndGet();
        maxActive.getAndAccumulate(actNow, Math::max);`